# Weirdness with media queries

Tags: media-queries

My LG Optimus One mobile has a resolution of 320x480. Yet only media queries with a max-width of 800px (and everyone knows that 320 = 800 !) are triggered on that mobile.

Any explanation?

Answer (score 5):

The explanation is that max-width query triggers for all sizes *smaller* than the specified *maximum* width.  If you'd like to restrict your stylesheet to 800px+, you'll need to use min-width 800px.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use this code in the head section:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

@mike hmm, I suspect you might be missing the  declaration in your . This should tell the browser to adjust it's viewport size to the width of the screen (i.e.: 320px) instead of the (arbitrary) desktop screen width it was provided with as a default (i.e.: 800px).

The following thread might help shed some light on this issue:
[Android browser reporting the wrong screen size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999000/android-browser-reporting-the-wrong-screen-size/8055216#8055216)